# (Reflective) Method call delivers same old results until app is force stopped and restarted (...is there something automatically cached somehow?)

Tags: android, caching, reflection, service, android-asynctask

I have a strange problem and hope that someone of you has an idea what happens here.

My app structure is as follows:

- I have a main service which registers a broadcast receiver and listens to intents like screen on/off etc. So this service runs indefinitely.
- When such an intent is received, I start another service which does the action
- Inside this action service I launch an AsyncTask to fetch battery related stats via reflection. After the service is done, it calls stopSelf().

So everything works as expected, except that when the battery related infos have been fetched one time, each subsequent call of the AsyncTask/Reflection methods deliver exactly the same result which has been delivered before.

The battery stats have of course been updated in the meantime, but I do not get the new updated numbers, but always the stats from the first method call.

That is until I go to settings and force stop and restart my app, then I get updated battery statistics again, at least one time, because after that I'm stuck with these numbers again.

So my question: 
Could it be that the results of the reflection call are automatically cached somewhere and that each subsequent call doesn't really fetch the new data but just delivers some cached results? What else could be the problem?

I'm thankful for any ideas, I you need some code lemme know :)

Comment: No, it's not possible. But it's possible that method itself caches it. Have You checked android source of method You're calling?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, maybe the method caches itself automatically? I did not check the android sources, for the reflection calls I use a library of Better Battery Stats by asksven. Since Better Battery Stats does not have this same problem (it always delivers refreshed results), I don't know why I have this issue :-/

Comment: May be some trivial issue in Your code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a fix to this :))

The library of Better Battery Stats uses the singleton pattern for a needed class.
It also includes an invalidate() function, which sets the singleton instance to null, so that at the next getInstance() it gets reinitialized.

I'm using now invalidate after each statisitics fetch, and now I get the updated statistics on every call. Although I am still not sure why the Singleton pattern seems to be the root of this issue, it should also work with having one initialized singleton instance...

Well, one does not simply have to understand everything ;-)